# Jquery achar proximo elemento dentro de uma div complexa

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Amigos, preciso encontrar um elemento em uma árvore `DOM` um pouco complexa e não estou conseguindo o resultado. Ao sair do `input id = "barcode"` eu adiciono novas linhas abaixo e preciso acionar o clique no próximo botão de leitor.

O código abaixo está com comentários que dá para entender melhor.

Estou usando o seguinte código ao sair do primeiro `input` porém não está funcionando:

```
var div_leitor = $('div.leitor').nextAll('div.leitor').first();
var barcode_clique = $(div_leitor).find('.barcode_btn');
$(barcode_clique).click();
```

O HTML e os comentários estão no gist bem como o js:
https://gist.github.com/rvgarimrj/cc8a6cb55364f9859e64785e1e0254bb

Alguém poderia me dar uma ajuda ? 
Obrigado

Comment: O que queres dizer com "sair" quando escreves _"Ao sair do input `id = "barcode"`"_?

Comment: O evento de focusout e tenho o código acima que não funciona. Preciso encontrar o proximo botao na próxima div e acionar o evento de clique.

Comment: Testa: `$('#barcode').on('focusout', function(){ $(this).closest('.nested-fields').next().find('.barcode_btn').click();});`

Comment: Estava a olhar melhor para esse HTML e parece-me estar errado... as divs `<div class="nested-fields">` não deveriam ser _siblings_? ou o HTML está mesmo correto e não estão no mesmo nível do DOM?

Comment: Tem algum erro neste código. Não está funcionando.

Comment: Viste a minha pergunta sobre o HTML aqui  ^  ?

Comment: Sergio, criei um gist com o html completo e meu js para você entender melhor. Veja se ajuda:
https://gist.github.com/rvgarimrj/cc8a6cb55364f9859e64785e1e0254bb

Comment: Podes colocar no gist o HTML renderizado? esse que colocaste vai ser processado certo?

Comment: Gist atualizado. Esse saida.html é o resultado da minha aplicaçao Rails já processado.Colquei os dois htmls que irão dar como saida este saida.html